# Using data from two different tables in the same database linked by role_id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got several tables in my database (MySQL) and am trying to link the data. I'm not sure a join is what I need, but I may be wrong. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to display the users role (admin, owner, etc) based on the role_id.  Here are the two tables I've got:

table: users

```
fields: user_id | role_id | user_name |etc (other fields)
```

table: user_roles

```
fields: role_id | role_name
```

I want the user's role (role_name) to display based on what the role_id is. It would sort of require linking data from user_roles and users, right? I'm honestly not sure. So, if role_id is 1 and role_name is Owner, I want role_name to be what displays BASED on the role_id in the users table. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from users, user_role.rolename
WHERE users.id = ??
AND user_role.role_id = users.role_id;
```

No need for joins!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, role_name, user_name, etc 
FROM users INNER JOIN user_roles USING(role_id)
WHERE <your conditions (if any)>;
```